# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in json_decode

Tags: php, json, laravel

in my laravel project i have column in database and in files name . 
i save files multiple size in json but when i try to decode this json i got this error

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

```
  @foreach($models as $model)
    <tr>
        <td class="tac">
            {!! Html::link(route('admin.files.edit', $model->id), $model->id) !!}
        </td>


        <td><img src="{{ json_decode($model->files) }}" /> </td>
        <td class="column-time">
            {!! Helpers::jDate($model) !!}
        </td>

    <td class="column-time">
            {!! Helpers::jDate($model) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

controller file

```
$models = $this->files->findAll();
return view("admin.files.index", compact("models"));
```

Json :

```
{"large":"/uploads/2015/04/81515adaaf9c747b_large.jpg","main":"/uploads/2015/04/81515adaaf9c747b_main.jpg","cover":"/uploads/2015/04/81515adaaf9c747b_cover.jpg","small":"/uploads/2015/04/81515adaaf9c747b_small.jpg","xsmall":"/uploads/2015/04/81515adaaf9c747b_xsmall.jpg"}
```

Comment: `json_decode` turns a JSON string into an array/object. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to use in that context. What would you expect that to do? What's the result supposed to be?

Comment: @deceze i know that, i just want to change it to array ,, take look at my error not my syntax and coding

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to stuff an object into an HTML attribute. That can't work. The attribute needs to be a string. Laravel is implicitly HTML-encoding attributes and that's where the problem manifests. Object !== string. Object !make-sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Since your json holds multiple images you have to get one to display:

```
<img src="{{ json_decode($model->files)->large }}" />
```

**Note** I believe this is only possible to do directly since PHP 5.4, but since that is the requirement for Laravel anyways, you should have no problems with it.